# Why was my comment on this question deleted?

Tags: discussion, comments

Well, I left a comment on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19471597/big-oh-notation-proof). Now it is gone. I assume it must have been deleted by one of our moderators.

Basically, I thought the question was about basic stuff and suggested a book that contains related details. It would be gone in a minute.

So why was my comment deleted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[What are comments](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment)

> Comments are *temporary* "Post-It" notes left on a question or answer. They can be up-voted (but not down-voted) and flagged, but do not generate reputation. There's no revision history, and when they are deleted they're gone for good.

Comments can be deleted for clean up purposes (ie tidy up if many people stating the same things) and can be deleted if they're flagged for being:

- rude or offensive
- not constructive
- obsolete
- too chatty
- other…

Either deleted by a mod looking at the flags, or if enough people vote for the same flag reason.

Try not to be bothered by your comments being removed. Sure maybe if it was prolific in some way or directed the questioner to their issue which then resulted in a good answer.
But even then, comments are supposed to be temp things to get to the answer, which is the point of the exercise  (ie Q&A, not Q,C&A ;) )

Comment: +1 Thanks James. I was just wondering what kind of comment is not appropriate on this site. However, I cannot find any issue regarding my comment so far.

Comment: There might not really be a real issue with your comment. People like to clean up, and if you suggested "Go get a book" you might have been justified if it was a weak question (etc), but people don;t like that as they want their question answered and answerers their rep for answering. Don't worry about it, "you can't please all the people.. etc.."

Comment: I was posting a link to the e-book. Never mind then. Thanks again.